# Flutter popUntil shows black screen

Tags: flutter

I am building a Flutter App. Right now I am on `/customers/id/edit/` route. In this route, a confirmation dialogue in the form of a bottom sheet is shown to the user. When he clicks Confirm button `_deleteCustomer` function is executed.

Now when the process has been completed, I want to take the user to the `/customers/` route. Which Navigator method should I use to do so? Right now, I am popping three times but this is not the right way to do things I guess.

I have tried `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/customers/'));`. But it shows a black screen. Any idea what could be wrong here?

```dart
// routes.dart

// Flutter imports:
import 'package:expense_app/config/theme.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/views/customers/create.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/views/customers/edit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

// Project imports:
import 'package:expense_app/views/customers/id.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/views/customers/index.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/views/home/index.dart';
import 'package:expense_app/views/transactions/index.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeView());
      case '/customers/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => FindCustomersView());
      case '/customers/create/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => CreateCustomerView());
      case '/customers/id/':
        final args = settings.arguments as FindOneCustomerViewArguments;
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => FindOneCustomerView(id: args.id));
      case '/customers/id/edit/':
        final args = settings.arguments as EditCustomerViewArguments;
        return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => EditCustomerView(id: args.id));
      default:
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: white,
            body: Container(child: Center(child: Text('Page Not Found'))),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
// edit.dart - connected to /customers/id/edit route

void _deleteCustomer(
    BuildContext context,
    CustomerController customerController,
    int id,
  ) {
    customerController.delete(id);
    SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Deleted Customer'));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it to return a black screen is that the '/customers/' route is not on the navigation stack.

Try this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/customers/', (ModalRoute.withName('The route before /customers/ route')));
```

Comment: This is somewhat right. Let me explain to you my path. I go from A > B > C > D, press Delete and the app should go to A > B. According to your answer, the only route in the stack is B. So when I press Back, it exits the app.

Comment: I have tried this `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/customers/', (ModalRoute.withName('/')));` but still doesn't work.

Comment: It still returns a black screen? Or Only route is customers

Comment: A Black screen.

Comment: This could happen if you are using MaterialApp in all the nested screens. Just use MaterialApp at one place and all other pages just use Scaffold

Comment: I am doing the same as you suggested.